# How to navigate with keyboard trough <mat-checkbox> in <mat-menu>

Tags: angular, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to navigate using keyboard trough checkbox list in angular material menu but without success. My code:

```
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="testMenu">Test</button>

  <mat-menu #testMenu="matMenu">
    <mat-checkbox role="menuitemcheckbox">Option 1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Option 2</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Option 3</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Option 4</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-menu>
```

When I'm opening menu the mat-menu-panel gets `tabindex="-1"`. I was trying to override it but nothing helps.

Angular version: 5.2.9

Can someone help?